# jQuery Multiple Dynamic Forms to Multiple Dynamic iFrames

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, sharepoint, iframe

I'm creating a multi-file upload.  In the validation process where I build the list of files (*before they are submitted*), the first dynamically created `<form>` will submit and work as expected but the other dynamically created `<form>`'s will not.  *This doesn't work in IE7+ or FireFox...*

Also to note, this code is in **SharePoint 2007** in case there are any restrictions anyone can point out! Thanks!

**Use Case**

1. User clicks browse and selects a file...
2. The `<input type="file" />` control is hidden.
3. jQuery wraps a `<form>` around the `<input type="file" />` and adds a new `<iframe>` that the form is referencing as the `target` for the response and submits the form.
4. On the server side, I run some validation and send back file name, size, and an option to remove.
5. In the `<iframe>` (response) the user sees something like **Winter.jpg |  10 KB  | (x) remove**
6. jQuery `clone()`'s the `<input type="file" class="uploader" />` control and `append()`'s it to the `<div>` in case the user desires to upload more.
7. **Note:**  keep in mind the `clone()`, `<form>`, and `<iframe>` are given unique IDs for the `id`, `name`, and `target` respectively.  The `.ashx` file has been tested and works.  I'm confused why I can't keep creating new `<form>`s, `<input type="file"/>`'s, and `<iframe>`'s and adding to the list...

**HTML**

```
<div id="files">
    <div class="field">
        <input id="file" type="file" name="file" class="uploader" value="Browse..." />
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**
*Sorry, the code might be a bit sloppy-- trial and error here...*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.uploader').live('change', function(){
        var $clone = $(this).parent().clone();
        var filename = $(this).val().substring($(this).val().lastIndexOf('\\')+1);

        //var $form = $('<form id="uploadForm" action="_layouts/GetFileInfo.ashx" method="post" target="fileinfo" enctype="multipart/form-data">');
        var $form = $('<form>').attr('id', 'uploadForm').attr('action', '_layouts/GetFileInfo.ashx').attr('method', 'post').attr('target', 'fileinfo').attr('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');
        var $result = $('<iframe name="fileinfo' + _uploadId + '" src="upload.html" frameBorder="0" allowtransparency="true" style="width: 250px; height: 25px; border:0;">');

        $form[0].id += _uploadId;
        $form[0].target += _uploadId;
        $clone.find('input')[0].id += _uploadId;
        $clone.find('input')[0].name += _uploadId;

        //remove button
        $('<div class="remove" style="float:right;">').html("x").appendTo($(this).parent());

        //append the goodness           
        $(this).parent().append($result);
        $(this).wrap($form);

        //let the form render and submit
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            $('#files form').last().submit();
        }, 1000);

        $(this).hide();

        $clone.find('input').val('');

        $(this).parents('#files').append($clone);

        _uploadId++;
    });
</script>
```

I figured you guys might ask so here's the rendered HTML...

**Rendered HTML**

```
<div style="float: left;" class="col" id="files">
    <div class="field">
        <form id="uploadForm0" action="_layouts/GetFileInfo.ashx" method="post" target="fileinfo0" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" value="Browse..." class="uploader" name="file" id="file" style="display: none;">
        </form>
        <div style="float: right;" class="remove">x</div>
        <iframe frameborder="0" style="width: 250px; height: 25px; border: 0pt none;" allowtransparency="true" src="upload.html" name="fileinfo0"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <form id="uploadForm1" action="_layouts/GetFileInfo.ashx" method="post" target="fileinfo1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" value="Browse..." class="uploader" name="file0" id="file0" style="display: none;">
        </form>
        <div style="float: right;" class="remove">x</div>
        <iframe frameborder="0" style="width: 250px; height: 25px; border: 0pt none;" allowtransparency="true" src="upload.html" name="fileinfo1"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
       <input type="file" value="Browse..." class="uploader" name="file01" id="file01">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: C'mon all you sexy devils...  I know you're out there, possibly just as mind-boggled as I but with JSFiddle in hand, ready to play me a tune? :) Don't worry- Bounty Cometh.  *BUMP*

Comment: I have upvoted your question, please have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277695/insert-data-into-textbox-when-checkbox-is-checked/9277746#9277746) question, if possible please give me an idea, i need an urgent solution

Comment: I know there is additional security around file inputs and iframes to prevent malicious scripters from reading a file from a user's computer without their permission/knowledge. It's possible you're running up against this type of restriction.

Comment: I made a JSFiddle for it and it seems it works in chrome and firefox. http://jsfiddle.net/mPVzH/ gonna test in ie later today.

Comment: +1 David, I'll look further into that. +1 @matdumsa, this is a pretty sharp fiddle and a lot of work done here.

Comment: What exactly do you need to use an iframe for instead of loading this data asynchronously into the same document?

Comment: @tandu, it is not possible to upload files using the browser's `XMLHttpRequest()` object so this method with `<iframe>`'s is proven to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All, this issue still remains but I implemented [jQuery Forms](http://jquery.malsup.com) (*which also works w/ multipart forms by using iframes*), changed the design a bit, and it works.

**If I had to guess, I think the issue was caused somewhere in creating the `<form>`, `<input type="file" />`, and other elements on-the-fly in JS.  It was as though SharePoint had a rule or listener that was incercepting the form `submit()` event and `return false;` not allowing it to get to the ASHX handler...**

I use the same HTML above, only now the JavaScript uses a single `<input type="file />` control and `<form>`.  I append the result via `$.ajaxSubmit({success: function(result)})`.

I still `clone()` the inputs and append them with the result.  When the user selects to upload the images I simply create a `<form>` object in JS and use `$.ajaxSubmit` on that as well.

I iterate thru the `context.Request.Files` in C# and attach them to the associated `ListItem` in SharePoint 2007.

Cheers,
Bobby

Comment: can you re-post a jsfiddle highlighting the problem? is the problem only happening in IE?

Comment: @matdumsa, the problem is in both IE and FF

Answer (score 0):

Try passing true to the clone() method. That keeps the data and the events binded.

Source: [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)

Comment: The jQuery `live()` event makes it so the events are attached without this but I did add `clone(true)` and got the same result.  This certainly was a nice try!

Answer (score 0):

According to me use jQuery clone function that can resolve your problem, here is the link http://api.jquery.com/clone/